# CSS last-child on list with <a> tags surrounding each <li>

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `<ul>` menu with some list items.  I used the :last-child pseudo class to apply a right border to the last list item.  Each previous list item has only a left border.  It looked fine, until I modified my HTML code to surround the list items with `<a>` tags.  I did this because I wanted the entire list item to be a clickable link.  Unfortunately, that broke my design because now, each list item was the last-child since it was nested within an `<a>` tag.  So now every list item has a left and right border.  How can I have the the right border only on the last list item and still retain a full clickable list item?

Here's the HTML I was using to test:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tabs__tab-list">
        <ul>
            <a href=""><li class="tabs__tab-list-item tabs__tab-list-item--active">Look Ups</li></a><!--
            --><a href=""><li class="tabs__tab-list-item">Look Up Types</li></a><!--
            --><a href=""><li class="tabs__tab-list-item">Look Up Relationships</li></a><!--
       --></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.tabs {
width: 70%;
margin: 20px;
min-height: 20px;
min-width: 700px;
display: block;
}

.tabs__tab-list {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.tabs__tab-list-item {
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    color: black;
}

.tabs__tab-list-item:hover {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

.tabs__tab-list-item:active {
    background-color: white;
}

 .tabs__tab-list-item:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.tabs__tab-list-item--current {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: You should not wrap your `<li>`s with the `<a>` element. This is invalid HTML markup!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to move the `<a/>` tags inside the `<li/>` tags, and set the `.tabs__tab-list-item` to `display: inline;`. See the snippet below

```css
html, body{
  width: 100%;
}
.tabs {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.tabs__tab-list {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.tabs__tab-list > ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }

.tabs__tab-list-item{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
}
.tabs__tab-list-item a{
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tabs__tab-list-item:hover {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

.tabs__tab-list-item:active,
.tabs__tab-list-item--active{
  background-color: white;
}

.tabs__tab-list-item:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.tabs__tab-list-item--current {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tabs__tab-list">
    <ul>
      <li class="tabs__tab-list-item tabs__tab-list-item--active">
        <a href="">Look Ups</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tabs__tab-list-item">
        <a href="">Look Up Types</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tabs__tab-list-item">
        <a href="">Look Up Relationships</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I wanted to have the entire "tab" be clickable, so instead I think I need to abandon the entire unordered list and just use <div> with inline-block display.  Is it incorrect syntax to surround a <div> tag with <a>?

Comment: @Sabien I updated the answer to make the anchors the full size of the tab.

Comment: Thanks.  After reading the CSS changes and looking up the properties I don't know, it looks like what makes the "clickable" area expand is the flex: 1 1 auto property, is that right?  Thanks for the update, this is the best of both worlds, retaining the HTML markup for meaning while doing what I want it to do and being correct HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The correct selector is now

```
a:last-child .tabs__tab-list-item
```

```css
.tabs {
width: 70%;
margin: 20px;
min-height: 20px;
min-width: 700px;
display: block;
}

.tabs__tab-list {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.tabs__tab-list-item {
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    color: black;
}

.tabs__tab-list-item:hover {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

.tabs__tab-list-item:active {
    background-color: white;
}

 a:last-child .tabs__tab-list-item {
     background-color: lightblue;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.tabs__tab-list-item--current {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tabs__tab-list">
        <ul>
            <a href=""><li class="tabs__tab-list-item tabs__tab-list-item--active">Look Ups</li></a><!--
            --><a href=""><li class="tabs__tab-list-item">Look Up Types</li></a><!--
            --><a href=""><li class="tabs__tab-list-item">Look Up Relationships</li></a><!--
       --></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works exactly how I want it to, but other answers have said that this is wrong because it's not correct HTML.  Why does the browser render it correctly if it's not correct HTML?

Comment: Yes, it's true that it is not correct HTML. The li should be direct descendants of ul. But the browsers don't really care about this. Also, since you are not using the list display, you can change the ul and the li for other types. You could use navbar instead of ul, and span instead of li, for instance, and everybody will be happy

Answer (score 1):

Surrounding the list items with a tags is invalid HTML. Just place the content of the list items into divs, and surround these divs with a tags and style them.

```
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tabs__tab-list">
    <ul>
      <li class="tabs__tab-list-item tabs__tab-list-item--active">
        <a href=""><div>Look Ups</div></a>
      </li>
      <li class="tabs__tab-list-item">
        <a href=""><div>Look Up Types</div></a>
      </li>
      <li class="tabs__tab-list-item">
        <a href=""><div>Look Up Relationships</div></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Knowing this was not the correct syntax for HTML prompted me go in a different direction without using an unordered list.  I want the entire box clickable, not just the text.

Answer (score 1):

Now you need to target the last `<a>` in the list, instead of

```
.tabs__tab-list-item:last-child
```

use

```
.tabs__tab-list a:last-child
```